# What method is called when i change activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-event

I have a MediaPlayer that keeps playing when I change activities and when I even click the physical Home button on my phone. How can I make it so that the MediaPlayer keeps playing when I change activities yet stops playing when I click the Home screen button?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA, What is your comment about? Please be more specific

Comment: @Egor I believe he is suggesting he needs to use a Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service. that keeps running the background.

the service is similar to normal activities but they run in background and dont have a user interface